# GDB 'info functions' only local to the binary?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to only show the functions that have been implemented by the binary being debugged in GDB? It doesn't seem that 'info functions' has any other options than a regex filter. I was thinking that it may be possible to view the memory addresses where the binary is located, then based on the location of the function address in a full 'info functions' determine if each is part of the binary, or part of something else. However, I dont know how to do that in gdb - I know vmmap shows this sort of information.

Anyone know how to do this? Suggestions?

Comment: Recent GDB (ie 7.5) is scriptable in Python, which could be relevant.

Comment: You could use `nm` to display all symbols (variables and functions though) with the following command `nm -C --defined-only my_binary | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | c++filt  | less`

Comment: nm may work, however i am trying this on osx. the arguments you passed are not supported in this version. also, the symbols shown from just 'nm [binary]' do not show up in the 'info functions' command in gdb...